# How to bucket a time stamp in 5 minute intervals in python

Tags: python

I am using python to increment a counter in 5 minute intervals in redis and speed of the execution code is rather important.  I will have a sorted set that will look like this:

```
1:30 incr 1:35 incr ...
```

where the incr is the hit count between that 5 minute interval.

Lets say I am at 1:32 pm and I want to place all of the hits between 1:30 and 1:35 in that bucket.

Naively I can just loop through a list and check if minute between 30 and 35 and place in the 1:30 bucket.  Is there a more pythonic method to do this?

Comment: Look at the time in *just* a minute representation. Does this lead to anything when coupled with an integral division and/or modulo?

Comment: I don't think so, usually you would loop through the list and populate a dict of lists using `bucket.setdefault(minute, []).append(hit)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from redis import Redis

r = Redis(db=1)
r.flushdb()
def store(t):
    h, m = map(int, t.split(':'))
    m = m - m % 5
    r.zincrby('tc', '%d:%02d' % (h, m), 1)

store('1:02')
store('1:30')
store('1:32')
store('1:35')

print r.zrange('tc', 0, -1, withscores=True)
```

Output:

```
[('1:00', 1.0), ('1:35', 1.0), ('1:30', 2.0)]
```